# Перенести отдельный коммит из другой ветки visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, git, gitlab, git-merge

Я могу переместить все изменения, используя функцию Visual Studio `Переместить изменения из одной ветви в другую`.

Есть способ перенести конкретный коммит?

Comment: `git cherry-pick your_commit_hash`

Comment: Есть же отличный инструмент под венду для работы с гит - TortoiseGit. То как это реализовано в студии это мягко говоря не удобно. А так да, в вашем распоряжении три варианта merge, rebase, cherry-pick. Всё по ситуации

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Допустим вы в ветке `dev` в правом нижнем углу кликаем по ветке и выбираем историю
[image: пункт view history]

В истории выбираем нужный коммит и прав.клик по нему -> View Commit Details
[image: выбор коммита в истории коммитов]

Далее переключаемся в ветку `master` или куда вы хотите перенести коммит
[image: переключение в ветку master]

Теперь можно выбрать пункт `cherry-pick`
[image: выбор пукта черри-пик]

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Нюанс для тех кто работает в студии 2017 - вначале переключаемся на ветку master, затем открываем историю dev и в контекстном меню коммита выбираем "отбор"/"cherry-pick".